# github error on create release: tag could not be created, pre-receive hooks failed

Tags: github, hook, release

I am not by any means a sophisticated github user.  I have learned the minimum handful of commands needed to add, commit, and push my project code to the public github.com repository.  So far it's been working fairly well... until today when I tried to create a new release (my third).

For some reason, when I try to publish my new release, I get the message

**Tag could not be created. Pre-receive hooks failed.**

I have never seen this message before.

I have tried various different tag names;  I have tried logging out and back in again;  I have tried pre-tagging on my local disk copy of the repo;  I have pushed and pulled (both ends are up to date).  This about exhausts my repertoire of things to try :-(

As a relative n00b I find this message incredibly opaque (sigh).  I have tried googling for it, but quickly got in over my head -- most of the hits I found were discussions about people setting up their own networked repos and installing or tweaking their own custom "pre-receive hooks", whereas I am just a dumb user of github.com apparently struggling with whatever "pre-receive hooks" they have installed (?).  If anyone can at least point me in the right direction I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 25):

Make sure you select the **tag version** in the dropdown.  The GitHub form will *let you submit* when this field is *blank*, but it will always display the mentioned error message.  (You do not need a 'v' prefix.).

**The latest Github form makes this more cryptic by having a dropdown titled 'Tag:Choose or Create" that hides the fact that this field is both required but not set.**

**Latest Github Form**
[image: GitHub Form 2]

**Older Github Form**
[image: GitHub Form]

Answer (score 1):

In a GitHub context, I have seen that [error message in this issue](https://github.com/trudK45/gxradar_pi/issues/6)

It could be a tag naming convention issue.
The [GitHub release documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/) recommends (enforces?) a tag following the [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) naming scheme: `vX.Y.Z`.

As [shown here](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/), try vx.y.z.

Comment: I just tried tag name v1.2.0 with the same result.  Does it matter how the files were tagged *before* they were uploaded to github?  I am not quite clear on the nature of the "release" tag vs any other tags that may have been applied between releases.

Comment: Yes the tag needs to be created first, before uploading the release. Check if there's a webhook declared in your GitHub repo.